# function adding space to array item

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function to filter CSS classes for duplicates and empty spaces, but my function exports arrays with empty spaces anyway...

```
var classes = function (className, current) {
    var classNames = [className], uniques = {};
    if(current) classNames = classNames.concat(current.split(' '));
    return classNames.filter(function (className,i) {
        if(className == "") return;
        className = className.match(/\S+/)[0];
       if (!uniques[className]) return uniques[className] = className;
    });
};
```

When I run `classes(' foo')` I get `[" foo"]` with a empty space anyway,
although `console.log(' foo'.match(/\S+/)[0];` returns `'foo'` with no space.

What am I missing?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzzBZ/)**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please provide more context.

Comment: @BlackSheep, thanks for looking at this. I want to pass `' foo'` into this function and get back a clean `['foo']` with no spaces. And I think I did everything correct but somewhere a empty space is being added and I can't find where...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand how `filter` works. From the [fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The return value from the callback tells `filter` which elements of `classNames` should be passed through, the return value is merely tested for truthiness. The return value of the callback isn't returned by `filter`, the original untouched values in `classNames` are. So the problem isn't that an extra space is being added, the problem is that nothing is removing the spaces.

If you want to test and modify at the same time then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) will serve you better:

```
return classNames.reduce(function(a, className) {
    if(!className)
        return a;
    className = className.match(/\S+/)[0];
    if(!uniques[className]) {
        a.push(className);
        uniques[className] = className;
    }
    return a;
}, []);
```

Note all the `return a;` statements and the lack of `return;`s.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/bw3JS/

You could also use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to clean up the spaces and then `filter` to clean up the `undefined`s with something like this:

```
return classNames.map(function(className) {
    if(!className)
        return;
    className = className.match(/\S+/)[0];
    if(!uniques[className])
        return uniques[className] = className;
}).filter(function(className) {
    return typeof className !== 'undefined';
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8j5Bb/

Comment: Aha... got the point... I'm changing the value of that iteration inside `.filter()` which is poinless. Good catch and thanks for a alternative solution!

Comment: I supose `.map()` also be a solution here. (?)

Comment: You could use `map` but each return value from the `map` callback ends up in the final array. `map` would leave you with `undefined` values or empty strings or some other value that you'd need a separate `filter` pass to clean up: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8j5Bb/